# Python with statements

Tags: python, raii, with-statement

I'm experimenting with Python's `with` statements, and I've found that in the following code listing my `__init__` method gets called twice, while my `__exit__` method gets called once. This presumably means that there will be a resource leak if this code did anything useful.

```
class MyResource:
    def __enter__(self):
        print 'Entering MyResource'
        return MyResource()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print 'Cleaning up MyResource'

    def __init__(self):
        print 'Constructing MyResource'

    def some_function(self):
        print 'Some function'

def main():
    with MyResource() as r:
        r.some_function()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

This is the program's output:

```
Constructing MyResource
Entering MyResource
Constructing MyResource
Some function
Cleaning up MyResource
```

I'm guessing it's because I'm doing something wrong in the `with` statement, effectively calling the constructor manually. How do I correct this?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It's rather obvious now in hindsight :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You shouldn't return a new instance from `__enter__`. Instead, return `self` (the instance for which `__enter__` is being called. That's why `__init__()` is called twice -- you call it twice, once in your with statement, once in `__enter__()`. Here's a correct version:

```
def __enter__(self):
    print 'Entering MyResource'
    return self
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason `__init__` is being invoked twice is since you call it twice:

Once when you initiate a `MyResource` object in the `with` statement and once more when the `with` statement invokes `__enter__` which in turn creates and returns a different instance of `MyResource`

Your `__enter__` method should return `self` instead.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you do not `return MyResource()` but `return self`, as `self` is the instance of the already constructed class.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to:

```
def __enter__(self):
    print 'Entering MyResource'
    return self
```

The `__enter__` method is there for you to do initialization, not to create your instance, it already exists (self).